# ruby match regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, require

I'm trying to require all the files in a folder. I have the following.

```
    Dir.foreach File.expand_path("app/models") do |file|
        require file unless file === /^\./
    end
```

However, it's failing. When I open up a ruby console, I try the following:

```
"." === /^\./
```

and it evaluates to false. Why won't it match?

Comment: That's just the way I've always done regex matching. I didn't realize that I had the operands flipped around though.

Comment: That's perhaps an argument for using `=~`, as order makes no difference: `r = /^\./; ".ab" =~ r #=> 0; r =~ ".ab" #=> 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `===` operator is actually a method of the object on the left.

The order of operands on the `===` matters in this case, because if the string literal `"."` comes first, the [String equality operator (method) `String#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is evaluated.  If the regex literal is placed on the left, [the Regexp operator `Regexp#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is used:

Reverse your operands.

```
# The string "." isn't equal to the Regexp object
>> "." === /^\./
=> false

# With the regexp as the left operand:
>> /^\./ === "."
=> true

# With the string on the left, you may use =~ and test for nil as a non-match
>> "." =~ /^\./
=> 0
```